# É possível criar um repositório remoto no github através do terminal?

Tags: git, github

Salve, pessoal. Estou com uma dúvida que não estou achando a resposta ou não estou sabendo procurar.

Seguinte, cheguei agora nesse universo de programação e estou aprendendo git. Mas me deparei com uma "debilidade" que eu senti que deveria existir um forma mais direta.

O problema é:

É possível criar um repositório no github através do terminal da minha máquina? (não tenho certeza se esses termos que estou usando estão corretos, mas acredito que vocês iram conseguir entender o que quero dizer)

Deixa eu esclarecer as circunstâncias:

Toda vez que eu preciso subir um repositório local para o remoto, eu tenho que ir lá no github, criar o repositório e só então dar o procedimento dos comandos "git remote add [https://github.com/euArteon/test.git"](https://github.com/euArteon/test.git%22) etc.

O que eu quero saber é se existe algum comando git que evite essa necessidade de ter que ir lá no site e criar o repositório? Em outras palavras, existe um comando para criar um repositório remoto através do terminal da minha máquina, ao invés de ter que ir lá no site do github?

Pesquisei sobre, mas não consegui encontrar essa informação, talvez porque não estou sabendo procurar. Na real, nem sei se é possível fazer esse "link".

Desde já, obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim (avalie se vale o esforço), segue abaixo:

```
curl -i -u user:pass -d "{\"name\":\"test\",\"private\":true}" https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

É necessário bater na API do github informando:

`-i` é para logar as informações durante a requisição;

`-u` seu usuário e senha (caso passe só o usuário, a senha será solicitada na sequência);

`-d` para informar que será passado algum "dado", neste caso um `JSON` com informações para a criação do repositório;

URL para criação do repositório - https://api.github.com/user/repos.

OBS: as \ são por conta do sistema operacional.

[Mais informações](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

Na primeira tentativa, recebi um email do Git informando que a autenticação básica informando a senha para a API deles está depreciada e em breve não funcionará mais. Junto deste email veio um link com uma alternativa, gerar um token no github e utiliza-lo para autenticação.

Segue email:

*On August 18th, 2020 at 13:04 (UTC) you used a password to access an endpoint through the GitHub API using curl/7.55.1:*

*https://api.github.com/user/repos*

*Basic authentication using a password to the API is deprecated and will soon no longer work. Visit https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/ for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.*

----- Atualizado

Testei utilizando o token, funciona praticamente da mesma forma:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token seu_token_aqui" -d "{\"name\":\"novo_repo\",\"private\":true}" https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Ao invés de informar `-u` para o usuário, você deve passar `-H "Authorization: token seu_token"`.

Para criação do token, [veja aqui](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: Resposta de alta qualidade! Muito obrigado mesmo! Ainda não sei como funciona o uso de api's, acredito que seja melhor continuar aprendendo o básico, pelo começo, mas as suas instruções são muito valiosas e vão me ajudar bastante no momento em que eu estiver aprendendo sobre. Muito obrigado mais uma vez!!